# Increase price by percentage, results rounded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and I need to update all the prices in my_table by 4%

I Found previous answers on stackoverflow and I know that the right way should be:

```
UPDATE my_table SET price = (price * 1.4)
```

but my clients wants the price to be rounded. So, if the result is 90,4 it must become 90, if 90.7 it must become 91.

Is it possible?

Comment: Column price data type?

Comment: `* 1.4` means 40 %...

Comment: yeah, it should be 40%; how's 4%? 1.04?

Comment: by the way, datatype is decimal(19, 4)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ROUND()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET price = ROUND(price * 1.4, 0);
```